# Debugging into C++ DLL in VS 2013 Express Web

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm developing a C# MVC project in Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web. An external C++ DLL is imported into the project and a function which is exported from the DLL is consumed.

I would like to be able to debug into the C++ DLL. However at the moment when I try to step into the function call the debugger steps over instead. The C++ DLL is one I created myself in Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows Desktop. I have generated the .pdb debug symbols for the DLL and they are in the same folder as the DLL.

I have read in similar posts that suggest perhaps there is a properties setting to enable debugging into external an DLL. However in the MVC 5 project properties I can't find this option. In fact there doesn't even appear to be a debugging tab.

Is debugging into an external C++ DLL possible in Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web? If it is how do I enable this feature? If it is not possible, is there another Visual Studio Express where this is possible?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have VS Express, but the following applies to VS Professional and should apply to Express as well. You need to set your Debugger Type to Native Only (best, but then you have to break in the native code to debug it) or Mixed (may or may not work, I don't use it, so not sure it's limitations), and make sure the DLL is freshly build and matches the source code you have available. I suspect the setting you refer to is called 'Just My Code' (in Options->Debugging), but I don't think it matters in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about VS2013 but with VS2015 you need to set "Enable Native Code Debugging". Right click on your C# project. In the right pane, click Debug. Under Enable Debuggers click the check box on Enable Native Code Debugging.